# recharts pie chart w/ value labels inside

Tags: reactjs, recharts

using the recharts library, i'd love to create a donut chart like this:
https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-donut/

specifically, the value labels are inside the pie chart segments. the only example i can find in the docs uses a custom renderLabel, but i was hoping with the new label component, this would be easier:
http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithCustomizedLabel

and following this example, this is the closest i can get, but the labels are not centered:
[image]

here is the the new Label component docs. i've tried: 
`<Label position="inside />`

here is the code for customLabelRendering:

```
const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
const renderCustomizedLabel = ({
  cx, cy, midAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius, percent, index,
}) => {
   const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.5;
  const x = cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * RADIAN);
  const y = cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * RADIAN);

  return (
    <text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor={x > cx ? 'start' : 'end'} dominantBaseline="central">
      {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`}
    </text>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you supplement the code?

Comment: http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithCustomizedLabel

Comment: I am asking for the code he had arrived to, where the labels are coming misaligned.

Comment: @godof23 i''ve updated the question with the specific section of that code that varoons linked and what i'm using to generate the labels now

Comment: A working code snippet / jsfiddle would be better, please.

Comment: the recharts link in my original question has a jsfiddle...

Comment: @godof23 there is a working jsfiddle in the links i posted...
https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/c9pL8k61/

Comment: textAnchor="middle" seemed to add some improvement for me.  I think it's the width and height of the text is kind of an unknown here and hard to offset.

Answer (score 11):

You can align the `<text />` label with `textAnchor="middle"` which will align them in the center for all cells.

Like this:

```
<text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor="middle" dominantBaseline="central">
  {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`}
</text>
```

You final code should look like this:

```
const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
const renderCustomizedLabel = ({
  cx, cy, midAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius, percent, index,
}) => {
   const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.5;
  const x = cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * RADIAN);
  const y = cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * RADIAN);

  return (
    <text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor="middle" dominantBaseline="central">
      {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`}
    </text>
  );
}
```

The above works for text, but if you need images in the center use `<svg />` and `<image />`.

```
return (
  <svg
    x={x - 12}
    y={y - 12}
    fill="#666"
    textAnchor={"middle"}
    dominantBaseline="central"
    width={24}
    height={24}
    viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
  >
    <image
      href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png"
      height="100%"
      width="100%"
    />
  </svg>
);
```

[image]